# replacing numpy array elements that are non zero

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 `numpy` arrays such as:

```
arr1 = np.array([[0,5,5,0],[0,5,5,0]])
arr2 = np.array([[7,7,0,0],[7,7,0,0]])
```

I'd like to copy non zero elements in `arr2` into corresponding position in `arr1` resulting the following array:

```
arr1 = np.array([[7,7,5,0],[7,7,5,0]])
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use three alternatives:

```
arr1[arr2 > 0] = arr2[arr2 > 0]
arr1[np.where(arr2>0)] = arr2[np.where(arr2>0)]
arr1[arr2.nonzero()] = arr2[arr2.nonzero()]
```

But a winner is `np.copyto(arr1, arr2, where=arr2 != 0)`, thanks @Mark Meyer.

Every of these 4 methods changes `arr1` into

```
array([[7, 7, 5, 0],
       [7, 7, 5, 0]])
```

If you don't want side effects in `arr1`, use `arr = arr1.copy()` instead and ten replace it in analogous way.

#### Update

Let's look at results of [perfplot](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot/)

```
import perfplot

def simple(arr):
    arr1, arr2 = arr
    arr1[arr2 != 0] = arr2[arr2 != 0]
    return arr1
def where(arr):
    arr1, arr2 = arr
    arr1[np.where(arr2 != 0)] = arr2[np.where(arr2 != 0)]
    return arr1
def nonzero(arr):
    arr1, arr2 = arr
    arr1[arr2.nonzero()] = arr2[arr2.nonzero()]
    return arr1
def simple_improve(arr):
    arr1, arr2 = arr
    idx = arr2 != 0
    arr1[idx] = arr2[idx]
    return arr1
def where_improve(arr):
    arr1, arr2 = arr
    idx = np.where(arr2 != 0)
    arr1[idx] = arr2[idx]
    return arr1
def nonzero_improve(arr):
    arr1, arr2 = arr
    idx = arr2.nonzero()
    arr1[idx] = arr2[idx]
    return arr1
def copyto(arr): #thanks @Mark Meyer
    arr1, arr2 = arr
    np.copyto(arr1, arr2, where=arr2 != 0)
    return arr1
import numexpr as ne
def copyto_numexpr(arr):
    #some magic boost
    arr1, arr2 = arr
    np.copyto(arr1, arr2, where=ne.evaluate('arr2 != 0'))
    return arr1

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: (np.tile(np.array([[0, 5, 5, 0], [0, 5, 5, 0]]), (n, n)),
                     np.tile(np.array([[7, 7, 0, 0], [7, 7, 0, 0]]), (n, n))),
    # setup=lambda n: [list(range(n))] * 10,
    kernels=[simple, where, nonzero,
             simple_improve, where_improve, nonzero_improve, 
             copyto, copyto_numexpr],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(12)],
    xlabel="n*n copies of array of shape (2,4)")
```

[image]

Comment: In performance wise which would be faster? I'm dealing with 20k*30k arrays here. @mathfux

Comment: I'm not sure, I guess that nonzero. Although, all the cases use repetition of the same indexes so this is double loss. Going to update an answer to measure it soon :)

Comment: So maybe declaring `a = arr2.nonzero()` and then using `arr1[a] = arr2[a]` could be a bit faster? @mathfux

Comment: Yes, sure. Let's look at the results on my update very soon.

Comment: Wait, oops! There is a new winner :(

Comment: Nice analysis @mathfux!

Comment: What is `ne`? Does it come from `import numexpr as ne`? Btw, nice analysis @mathfux!

Comment: @CypherX Yes, it is. `numexpr` gives a microscopic boost only when evaluated on a single operation `a != b`

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to mutate `arr1`, you can just assign with [boolean indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing):

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([[0,5,5,0],[0,5,5,0]])
arr2 = np.array([[7,7,0,0],[7,7,0,0]])

arr1[arr2 != 0] = arr2[arr2 != 0]

print(arr1)

# [[7 7 5 0]
#  [7 7 5 0]]
```

You can pick up a little performance on large arrays using [`copyto()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.copyto.html#numpy.copyto):

```
np.copyto(arr1, arr2, where=arr2 != 0)
```